# Calling toUppercase() on a string variable

Tags: javascript, methods

I'm a beginner and just successfully trouble-shoot my code. I'm glad that I found it, however it took me a long time. I'm hoping to learn why it happened.

Here's the buggy original code. Assume that the variable `[nextAlpha]` has already been assigned a string value:

```
nextAlpha.toUpperCase();
```

Through some creative testing I was able to determine it was the line causing issues. I thought perhaps it's not actually updating the value of variable `[nextAlpha]`. I tried this instead, and it worked:

```
nextAlpha = nextAlpha.toUpperCase();
```

I've left the rest of my code out, but assume that `[var = nextAlpha]` has already been declared at the top of my script, which I think means "globally." With that information, I thought it was enough to simply call the method on the variable. Why doesn't this "update" the string to upper case like it does when I go the extra step to (re)assign it to the original `[nextAlpha]` string?

Comment: when you use nextAlpha.toUpperCase(); it generates a string so you need to assign this value to some reference here you are assigning back to nextAlpha.It's not a bug.

Comment: Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toUpperCase` returns the converted string as a new object - it does not perform the conversion on `nextAlpha`.

From the Mozilla reference:

> The toUpperCase method returns the value of the string converted to uppercase. toUpperCase does not affect the value of the string itself.

[reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase)

Comment: Thanks for this. For clarification, if I declare [var = nextAlpha] earlier in the code, then later on I declare [nextAlpha = nextAlpha.toUpperCase()], what am I doing here? Am I creating a new string with the same name? Am I "reassigning" it? Because I now understand that strings are immutable, but in my code I just updated the string's value. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Yes, you're assigning a new value (the uppercased string) to `nextAlpha`.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, Strings are immutable:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

> Unlike in languages like C, JavaScript strings are immutable. This means that once a string is created, it is not possible to modify it. However, it is still possible to create another string based on an operation on the original string

Answer (score 1):

`toUpperCase()` is a function (so return a value) not a property (affect the variable itself)